# ajax callback window.location Request Aborted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window.location

I am currently trying to create a client-side reroute for users that are invalid. The server validates if the user has access to the current page and if not it returns `{data: 'invalid'}` in the `success` callback of the ajax call I check this value with the following:

```
if (data.status === 'invalid') {
    window.location.href = domain + '/login';
    return false;
}
```

This works sometimes but other times I receive the following browser alert message:

> RequestAbortedError: Request aborted

I have attempted to swap out `window.location.href` with `window.location.replace()` and `top.location.href` but neither resolved the issue.  I can see that the server is processing the information correctly and returning `{data: 'invalid'}` but as soon as it tries to run the line `window.location.href` I receive this error.  I have an image below if it helps.

[image]

When "OK" is clicked the page does redirect to the appropriate page.  The end result is happening as expected but I cannot resolve the error.

**UPDATE INCLUDING SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
function authentication (req, res, next) {
    console.log('entered');
    if (typeof req.rsaConPortal.email !== 'undefined') { // Check if session exists
        console.log('passed 1');
        User.findOne({ "user.email": req.rsaConPortal.email, "user.status”: req.resConPortal.status}, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                console.log('failed 2');
                req.rsaConPortal.reset();
                res.send({status: 'invalid'});
            } else {
                console.log('passed 2');
                req.rsaConPortal.email = user.user.email;
                req.rsaConPortal.id = user._id;
                req.rsaConPortal.status = user.user.status;

                next();
            } 
        });
    } else {
        console.log('failed 1');
        res.send({status: 'invalid'});
    }
}

app.get('/api/savedApp/', authentication, function(req, res) {

    if (req.rsaConPortal.status !== 'registered') {
        res.send({status: 'invalid'});
    } else {

        User.find({ "_id": req.rsaConPortal.id }, {
            profile: 1, documents: 1 }, function(err, user) {

            if (err) throw err;

            res.send(user);
        });  
    }    
});
```

Is there a better way to authenticate my users?  I am using Mozilla's Client-Sessions npm package

The logs on the server are logging "Passed1" and "Passed2".  It is sending the client "Invalid" based off the status inside the `get` call.

Comment: If you're setting the URL, thus navigating away from the current page, why bother returning false? (serious question)

Comment: what does `window.location.href` output in the console?

Comment: @enhzflep since I am utilizing ajax I thought it is not possible to redirect from the server.  My understanding is that I need to pass info from the server and have the client side javascript handle the redirect with ajax.

Comment: @Scaramouche Not sure how to `console.log` the command  `window.location.href` as I stated in the question the redirect is happening as expected.

Comment: ok then, try doing `console.log(domain + '/login')` before assigning it to `window.location.href`

Comment: @Scaramouche that logs the desired url that I want it to redirect to

Comment: @CraigHowell Can we see the code on the server side or any error logs?

Comment: @LoganBertram I have included the server side code in my question.  The only error I am seeing is the browser alert.  Nothing appears in the console or in my server logs.

Comment: @CraigHowell - AJAX lets you pull/push things in without leaving the page. Snce you actually _want_ to leave, ajax has nothing to do with the act of leaving - it was only important for finding out if you should or not. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep I understand that. That is why I am either returning the data necessary for the page or a status of invalid. The. I run a check for invalid in the success call back to determine if the user should stay and load the data or should be redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on reading further about express and a few comments I have received on this question I have decided to re-think my approach and look for a better alternative which I am happy to say I have found in express.Router.  I was able to create an authentication function to determine if the user is authorized and handle the business logic of whether to let the user pass or send them back to the login.  Then I created a route for each page that I have that takes the business logic a step further based on the users status and either lets them pass or sends them back to login.

Thanks to everyone who looked into this and provided comments.

```
var router = express.Router();
app.use(router);

var authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.rsaConPortal !== undefined) {
        if (req.rsaConPortal.email !== undefined) { // Check if session exists
            // lookup the user in the DB by pulling their email from the session
            User.findOne({ "user.email": req.rsaConPortal.email, "user.password": req.rsaConPortal.passport }, function (err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    // if the user isn't found in the DB, reset the session info and
                    // redirect the user to the login page
                    req.rsaConPortal.reset();
                    req.rsaConPortal.email = '';
                    req.rsaConPortal.passport = '';
                    req.rsaConPortal.id = '';
                    req.rsaConPortal.status = '';

                    res.redirect('../login');
                } else {
                    req.rsaConPortal.email = user.user.email;
                    req.rsaConPortal.passport = user.user.password;
                    req.rsaConPortal.id = user._id + '';
                    req.rsaConPortal.status = user.user.status;

                    next();
                } 
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect('../login');
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect('../login');
    }
};

router.get(['/','/create_warranty','/help','/marketing_assets','my_documents','profile'], authenticate, function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.rsaConPortal.status !== 'approved') {
        res.redirect('../login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```